# Ascii doctor gradle jvm plugin is not generating the html file

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, asciidoctor

I have a project which is having the below dependencies for ascii doctor:

```
dependencies {
        // Used by api documentation generator
        classpath 'org.asciidoctor:asciidoctor-gradle-jvm:3.3.2'
}

apply plugin: 'org.asciidoctor.jvm.convert'
```

I have configured a gradle task to generate the html report for my ascii documents as below:

```
asciidoctor {
    sourceDir = asciidocOutputDir
    sources {
        include 'apidocs.adoc'
    }
    outputOptions {
        backends = [ 'html5' ]
        attributes = [
                doctype    : 'book',
                toc        : 'left',
                toclevels  : '3',
                numbered   : '',
                sectlinks  : '',
                sectanchors: '',
                hardbreaks : '',
                generated  : asciidocOutputDir
        ]
    }
}
```

This gradle task is running successfully but the html file is not getting generated under my build folder. I am using gradle 7.3.3 with JDK11.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can have a look at https://asciidoctor.github.io/asciidoctor-gradle-plugin/development-3.x/user-guide/ it shows how to configure the plugin correctly. What you could try:

- use the plugin directly from gradle

```
    plugins {
    id 'org.asciidoctor.jvm.convert' version '3.1.0'
    }
```

- rename your file to something different and check whether an error occurs
- remove as much configuration as possible until it runs and then add it step by step to find the issue
- your asciidoctor file should live under `src/docs/asciidoc`
- do a `gradlew clean` before asciidoctor task
- is there something interesting the gradle output

It's always difficult to say what needs to be changed if only a part of the setup is present. Is it possible that you can share the complete example on github or elsewhere?